# Google maps API v2 authentication error in Release mode - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, keytool

I have been working on android maps. Maps were working fine when I build it from my PC but when I generate APK and test it on other mobiles. I am unable to view the maps. I have followed the below procedure

I got SHA-1 key using the following command

keytool -list -v -alias "myalias" -keystore "mykeystorepath" -storepass "" -keypass

And then I generated the API key from Google developers console. I used the obtained key in my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="mykey" />
```

Comment: Are you using one API key for both debug and release, or two separate API keys?

Comment: I am using same key for debug and release. How can i generate a key for release?

Comment: It's fine to do it that way.  Do you have both your debug and release sha1 fingerprints in the one API key?

Comment: I have only one sha1 fingerprint. Which I used to generate API key as mentioned above.

Comment: You need both the debug and release sha1 fingerprints in the API key.  If you have only one in the API key, is it the debug one or the release one?